# Compute $\int_{0}^{\pi /2} f(x) dx$ with cos condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function which satisfies 
>   $$\int_{0}^x tf(x-t)dt=1-\cos x$$
>   Compute $\int_0^{\pi /2}f(x)dx$.

My attempt: I've tried to simplify the condition to $-x\int_0^xf(t)dt+\int_0^x tf(t)dt=1-\cos x$ and plug $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ into ths equation, but then I have difficulty on finding $\int_o^{\pi /2}xf(x) dx$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: From your original simplification, differentiate both sides twice, using the fundamental theorem.

Comment: You have a sign error, $$\int_0^x g(t)\,dt = \int_0^x g(x-u)\,du.$$ Doesn't matter much, but you'd get a wrong sign of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $t:=x-\tau$ we obtain the condition
$$\int_0^x(x-\tau)f(\tau)\>d\tau=1-\cos x\ .\tag{1}$$
Denote by $F$ the (unknown) primitive of $f$ assuming the value $F(0)=0$. Partial integration of the LHS of $(1)$ then leads to
$$\int_0^x(x-\tau)f(\tau)\>d\tau=\ (x-\tau)F(\tau)\biggr|_{\tau=0}^x+\int_0^x F(\tau)\>d\tau=\int_0^x F(\tau)\>d\tau\ ,$$
so that we now have
$$\int_0^x F(\tau)\>d\tau=1-\cos x\tag{2}$$
instead of $(1)$. If we differentiate $(2)$ with respect to $x$ we obtain $F(x)=\sin x$, hence $$f(x)=F'(x)=\cos x\ .$$ It is easy to check that this $f$ indeed fulfills the original condition.